# retrieve list values and change the values with user input

Tags: python, list

I have a string of product parts = 'ABCDEFGHIJKL'.
Each letter suppose to have a starting value of 100.
The user is supposed to add numbers to the specific letter of their choosing and the value of that letter will be updated accordingly.
I'm not supposed to use dictionary for this code.
I wrote what I roughtly know except those with [?]

```
def updateInventory():
    startLevel = 100
    partIds = 'ABCDE'
    stockLevel = [startLevel] * len(partIds)
    productCodes = []
    while True:
        partIdentifier = input("Enter part identifier or <ENTER> to end: ").upper()
        if partIdentifier == '':
            break
        # partIdentifier must be in partIds
        if partIdentifier not in partIds:
            print("The part identifier is invalid")
        else:
            #print the part and its current quantity
            print(f"Current stock level for {partIdentifier} = [?]")
            while True:
                # user tp input how much quantity to add
                quantity = int(input("Enter quantity to add: "))
                if quantity < 0:
                    print("The quantity is invalid")
                else:
                    partIds[partIdentifier] += quantity
                    print(f"Updated stock level for {partIdentifier} = [?]")
                    break
updateInventory()
```

Example run

```
Enter part identifier or ENTER to end: T

The part identifier is invalid

Enter part identifier or ENTER to end: E

Current stock level for E = 100

Enter quantity to add: 0

The quantity is invalid

Enter part identifier or ENTER to end: E

Current stock level for E = 100

Enter quantity to add: 25

Updated stock level for E = 125
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what you are doing is you are only displaying the new value but you are not updating the `partIds` dict.

Here is the full code;

```
def updateInventory():
    partIds = {'A': 100,'B': 100,'C': 100,'D': 100,'E': 100,'F': 100,'G': 100}
    while True:
        partIdentifier = input("Enter part identifier or <Enter> to end: ").upper()
        if partIdentifier == '':    # break the loop if the user press enter
            break
        # check the validity of the partIdentifier
        if partIdentifier not in partIds.keys():
            print("The part identifier is invalid")
        else:
            print(f"Current stock level for {partIdentifier} = {partIds[partIdentifier]}")
            # check if the amount entered by the user is acceptable
            while True:
                quantity = int(input("Enter quantity to add: "))
                if quantity <= 0:
                    print("The quantity is invalid")
                else:
                    partIds[partIdentifier] += quantity # here i am adding 'quantity' to the older value of the part identifier
                    print(f"Updated stock level for {partIdentifier} = {partIds[partIdentifier]}")

                    print("partIds: ", partIds)
                    break

updateInventory()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `1` as your dict keys in your `print` statements instead of `partIdentifier`. Added the addition of the quantity to the second part, I think that's what you wanted, it won't get added if you do it in the middle of an f-string unless you use a `:=`.

Also, you can check if a key is in a dict without `.keys()`.

```
def updateInventory():
    partIds = {'A': 100, 'B': 100, 'C': 100, 'D': 100, 'E': 100, 'F': 100, 'G': 100}
    while True:
        partIdentifier = input("Enter part identifier or <Enter> to end: ").upper()
        if partIdentifier == '':  # break the loop if the user press enter
            break
        # check the validity of the partIdentifier
        if partIdentifier not in partIds:
            print("The part identifier is invalid")
        else:
            print(f"Current stock level for {partIdentifier} = {partIds[partIdentifier]}")
            # check if the amount entered by the user is acceptable
            while True:
                quantity = int(input("Enter quantity to add: "))
                if quantity <= 0:
                    print("The quantity is invalid")
                else:
                    partIds[partIdentifier] += quantity
                    print(f"Updated stock level for {partIdentifier} = {partIds[partIdentifier]}")
                    break


updateInventory()
```